# In House Distribution : re-installing an app over an existing one, leaves app in error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, distribution

I have an application ready for internal distribution. I created the manifest file and a simple download page in order to download the app from a personal server.

If the app is not installed in the device, the application is downloaded and installed without problems.
Once the app is installed, If I hit the download button again, iOs ask me if I want to install the app, just like the first time, and then the download starts.

After the second download finishes, I tap on the icon but the application refuses to start and the console on the iPhone Configuration Utility throws the following

```
The 'MyApp' bundle at /private/var/mobile/Applications/15F088EB-B996-48CE-8331-A5CE85CDD74F/myapp.app does not have an executable path. Please check the bundle's Info.plist file.
```

Weird things:

1 - When having this error, if I shut down the device by holding the sleep button a few seconds and restart the device again, the app start working again.

2 - Let's say I myapp.app that has a bundle version 1.0 hosted in my server. I install it on the device for the first time and it works. Then I upgrade the hosted version to a bundle version 2.0 and perform the same download again, the app upgrades and launches without problems.

Question 1: Any ideas?
Question 2: Is there a way to handle this version difference? I mean, as a simple workaround, it would be great if I can display something like: "Your version is up to date" and do not download the new package

Thanks!!!

Comment: Issues with case-sensitivity, at a guess?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not quite sure about your comment.. what do you mean with a case-sensitivity issue ?

Comment: The path appears to be "myapp.app", whereas the bundle name is "MyApp". Are you sure you don't mean "MyApp.app"?

Comment: Hi Omer, did you figure this out ? This is the exact problem we have ...

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue too.. Any fixes????

Comment: I tested everything without success, including case-sensitivity...

Comment: I've started seeing this randomly happen too, for no obvious reason. Sigh :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked for me is really simple. Before deploying a new version, modify the "Bundle version" and "Bundle version string, short" values in the Info.plist file to reflect a new version. For example if the installed app has "Bundle version" 1.0, use 1.1. Same for Bundle version string, short too.

Comment: you are right, but this is not what I needed to solve, I need for the application not to broke if a user downloads the same version twice. BTW: your answer is the point no. 2 in the Weird things section of my questions =D.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and have found a Strange solution using windows unzip and zip...

The cause of this problem for me was repackaging the ipa with a customer specific file after the initial build.  So this may or may not work for you as I do not know the root cause of your problem.

My ipa, installation plist and an installation html file are hosted on an internal Windows Server 2003 running Tomcat.

Forgot to add this before, but the 'zip/unzip' used were from Symbian common files...

Required Installations:  (We install these by default as part of our client customer build and provisioning systems)

1. Perl (ActivePerl 5.6.1)
2. S60 3RD EDITION SDK FOR SYMBIAN OS (9.1)

SOLUTION:

1. Ensure path includes "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\tools" and "..\Perl\bin"
2. open a prompt at the location of the ipa file.
3. Unzip the ipa using "unzip myapp.ipa" after which you should see the 'Payload' folder.
4. Re-zip the package using "zip -r mynewapp.ipa Payload"

and viola, for me the newly zipped ipa can be installed over itself without causing the error you and I were both seeing.

I'm not sure if any other zip/unzip will work in the same way as Symbians tools do, but as I require it to be installed for legacy s60 provisioning that is what I used.  This solves my issue so I've now scripted a deployment mechanism that does this re-zipping when releasing a new version.

When creating the deployment script I also found that the zip command produced different results if not run from the same directory as the files.  The resulting ipa in that case was uninstallable, so make sure you change to the directory containing the ipa before using unzip and zip.

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify two keys (CFBundleVersion & CFBundleShortVersionString) in Info.plist.

> CFBundleVersion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the build version number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or unreleased) of the bundle. The build version number should be a string comprised of three non-negative, period-separated integers with the first integer being greater than zero. The string should only contain numeric (0-9) and period (.) characters. Leading zeros are truncated from each integer and will be ignored (that is, 1.02.3 is equivalent to 1.2.3). This key is not localizable.
>
> CFBundleShortVersionString specifies the release version number of the bundle, which identifies a released iteration of the app.

You can add the CFBundleVersion by 1 every time when you build an adhoc version for your test or user with the same release version(CFBundleShortVersionString)

For example : your CFBundleShortVersionString is 1.2.3, your CFBundleVersion is 1000. when you fix a bug and build an adhoc version for testing, you can change CFBundleShortVersionString to 1001.